# Is it possible to use webassembly in QNX

Tags: browser, c++, web, javascript, qnx

I’m trying to figure out if I’m able to port a webassembly based webapplication to QNX. But it is hard to find any information about what versions of browsers and web engine libraries that are shipped with what version of QNX and what features they support.

SDP 7.x (which I believe is used with QNX 7 and CAR 3?) seems to be shipped together with a modernized browser based on the Blink engine (instead of the webkit lib used in QNX 6).

[It uses uses the V8 JavaScript engine](https://blackberry.qnx.com/content/dam/qnx/products/qnxcar/QNX_WebBrowser_ProductBrief_FINAL.pdf)

[which supports webassembly](https://v8.dev/)

So the browser in it self should support webassembly, right?

I guess the webassembly code created with Emscriptens should be able to be compiled on any platform and transferred to the QNX system. Cause I believe Emscriptens wont run correctly on QNX? Or can I compile Emscripten with q++ on QNX and create the webassemby directly on the QNX system? I'm not sure I understood it correctly. But it seems like Emscripten should be able to compile and run on any system that can use LLVM, which QNX does.

Can anyone with a bit more QNX knowledge confirm if this might be possible or not?